# MS Test "Method not found: System.String" Error

Tags: unit-testing, mstest

Since recently some of my MS Test unit tests have stopped working. I haven't changed anything in the tests themselves. The error I am getting is the following:

> Test Failed - [file name]
>
> Message: Method not found: 'System.String Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestResult.get_TestContextMessages()'.

Under 'References', in my unit test Project (in Visual Studio), I have the following:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.Interface
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework
>
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions
>
> Moq
>
> Ploeh.AutoFixture
>
> Ploeh.AutoFixture.AutoMoq

Anybody know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the problem essentially is what I described in the last comment, i.e. if you create a new Unit Test project in Visual Studio 2015, it comes with **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework** already installed. If you then install **MSTest.TestFramework** from NuGet, which is going to be MSTest version 2 (this is important to note), this is going to create Ambiguous Reference issue for test attributes such as **TestClass** and **TestInitialize**, i.e. the Unit Test project doesn't compile.

To resolve the issue above, the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework** reference can be removed from the project. That makes everything work fine, which was the case with my project. After some time though, for an unknown reason, something got corrupted in my Unit Test project and I started getting the error in the original post. To resolve this, I created a new Unit Test project, moved all of my unit tests to it, added a reference **MSTest.TestFramework** and deleted the one to **Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework**.

[Here](https://codexample.org/questions/313018/expectedexception-ignored-by-mstest-v2-when-running-from-the-command-line.c) is a related issue.

Comment: If this approach has resolved the issue, you may want to mark it as an answer :)! It will help others with similar issue.

Comment: Right. I just have to wait till tomorrow.

Comment: In VB.NET I had to remove the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework reference manually from the .vbproj file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you also referenced Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll? I don't see it in mentioned project references. This library is referenced in MS test projects by default though.

Also, see if the processor architecture of the tests and target project are same. Processor architecture of the test can be checked from menu Test->Test Settings->Default Processor Architecture. Possibly it would need to be changed to x64.

Comment: I had it in there at some point a while back, but then I had to take it out (for a reason i am forgetting now). I think my tests worked without it thought. Anyway, I tried to install it just now from NuGet and i got this error: Could not install package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework 11.0.50727.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Also, I set the processor architecture of my unit test project to x64, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Now I remember why I had to remove the reference to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework'. It creates an ambiguous reference issue for the test attributes, such as 'TestClass' and 'TestInitialize'. To reproduce this, I just created a new Unit Test project in Visual Studio 2015 and that came with 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework' already installed. Then I had to install 'MSTest.TestFramework' and that created the same problem, i.e. ambiguous references for 'TestClassAttribute'.